# How should I grab data 3 values in and the codes at the end?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to create Value IDs from text data that isn't always the most helpful. My company is using Excel and SQL currently.

I have "BTA Canvas Taupe (#5461-0000)" and I need to create formulas to have "A.5461-0000". Currently I have this:

```
=CONCAT(MID(A6,3,1),".",IF(TRIM(CLEAN(IFERROR(RIGHT(A6,LEN(A6)-SEARCH("#",A6)),A6)))="",A6,TRIM(CLEAN(IFERROR(RIGHT(A6,LEN(A6)-SEARCH("#",A6)),A6)))))
```

It returns `A.5461-0000)`

How to get that last ")" off?

Comment: Look into `SUBSTITUTE`

Comment: Is the length of the "####-####" not static?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you P.B, The substitute was the answer! Here is it working:
=SUBSTITUTE(CONCAT(MID(A6,3,1),".",IF(TRIM(CLEAN(IFERROR(RIGHT(A6,LEN(A6)-SEARCH("#",A6)),A6)))="",A6,TRIM(CLEAN(IFERROR(RIGHT(A6,LEN(A6)-SEARCH("#",A6)),A6))))),")","")

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

1. your original text string always ends with `)`
2. your original text string is in cell `A1`

You can use a combination of **&**, **MID**, **FIND**, and **LEN** functions to work out the target string:

```
=MID(A1,3,1)&"."&MID(A1,FIND("#",A1)+1,LEN(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("#",A1)))-1)
```

Here is an alternative solution using **FILTERXML** function to find the serial number:

```
=MID(A1,3,1)&"."&FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1),"#","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","a/b[2]")
```

[image: Solution Screenshot]